# How to iterate multiple Gdb's and their Feature classes to add fields into each of them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I created 3 gdb's under the home project gdb and created 3 point feature classes in each respectively. How do I iterate through all the file gdb's and add fields into each of them?

[gdbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxDFv.png)

My script:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/..."

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for ds in datasets:
    arcpy.management.Compact(ds)
    for fc in featureclasses:
        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "FACILITYID", "TEXT", field_length=20,
                                  field_alias="Facility Identifier", field_is_nullable="NON_NULLABLE")

        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "INTID", "LONG",
                                  field_alias="Integer ID", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")

        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "LASTUPDATE", "DATE",
                                  field_alias="Last Update Date", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")

        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "LASTEDITOR", "TEXT", field_length=20,
                                  field_alias="Last Editor", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")

        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "NOTES", "TEXT",
                                  field_alias="Notes", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")

        arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "ENTERPRISEID", "TEXT", field_length=20,
                                  field_alias="Enterprise ID", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE")
```

It didn't work, I'm probably not using the right functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ListWorkspace`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listworkspaces.htm) instead of `ListDatasets`:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/some/folder"

for gdb in arcpy.ListWorkspaces(workspace_type="FileGDB"):
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*"):
        # Add fields to the feature class
```